# Cannot access a part of a particular website on iphone only

Tags: network, google-chrome, iphone

As ridiculous as this is, its a real issue that I have to deal with intermittently.
Every now and then, I can't access any of the messages on the onlyfans website while using an iphone. It works fine on my android phone, works fine on windows desktop and apple laptop but iphone 13 - nope.

I'd get it if it was some weird browser kink but on the iphone, I tried chrome, safari and firefox and they all behave exactly the same. I go to the website, tap on messages, tap on any of the users that sent me a message and then just blank screen and nothing. Every other website and literally everything else that I normally do with the phone works fine.

I tried clearing browser caches, reinstalling browsers, killing any other apps, restarting the iphone and my network stack, listening to javascript errors but to no avail, it just says nothing and doesn't work.

This has happened before and after a while it just fixes itself...

Does anybody have a clue as to what this may be?

Comment: When this happens, put the phone in Airplane mode, then normal mode, the restart the phone.  This resets DNS..  See if this works.  Otherwise it is off topic here,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because belongs in Ask Different

Comment: In Safari, what if you tap the "Aa" menu and "request desktop website?" Also some websites, I have noticed, don't test with Safari, and as that is the **ONLY** page renderer Apple allows on the iPhone, I wonder if that may be an issue. Does it exhibit the same issues in Safari on a Mac?

Comment: how do you get internet? Mobile data? Is it the same if wifi? If wifi is it the same on another wifi or mobile data?